# Go Lang Return JSON

Tags: json, go

Still pretty new with Go. I'm trying to get go to essentially print a struct with the keys and values as close to json as possible.

The way I'm currently doing this is having GO on it's own server and whenever a get request is made, it returns the JSON. I would like to have GO as an executable on my primary Rails server and just return the JSON with something like Println (or whatever would make it stay in struct form). The problem is when I try to go this route, the keys from the struct aren't printed with it and I would basically have to add the keys as part of the return string.

Is there a simple way to do this with keeping the correct keys and values (and their types, so if the value is an array, keep the array)

Comment: Can you show the current code that you have printing the struct without their keys?

Answer (score 2):

Printing a struct as JSON to STDOUT is fairly straight forward in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    foo := struct {
        Hello string
        JSON  string
    }{
        Hello: "world",
        JSON:  "stuff",
    }

    fmt.Printf("foo struct : %+v\n", foo)

    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(foo); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/wqqGJ1V_Zg

That program will output the following:

```
foo struct : {Hello:world JSON:stuff}
{"Hello":"world","JSON":"stuff"}
```

From your question I really didn't understand what you meant. In any case, if you wanted to print the struct as JSON or if you just wanted to print the struct as close to JSON as possible your answer is there.

Comment: Hmm let me try this with my current code and see if it does that. I feel like I did it exactly like that before and it wasn't printing the keys of the structs for some reason. I'll comment on this in a few hours when I'm back to my work computer, thanks Leo.

Comment: Hey so I finally got around to checking out your answer. Sorry it took so long. So your example output only outputs:
`foo struct : {Hello:world JSON:stuff}`
Unfortunately I really need the quotes and commas like a normal JSON strong would have, so I don't think this way would work. Thanks though

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Why do you want to write out the struct as close as possible to JSON? You could just print out it's JSON representation which is the second line of that output by using `json.NewEncoder`

Comment: If your problem is its not printing out the keys, make sure your keys all start with an uppercase letter. Lowercase signifies that it is not exported, so the encoding/json package will not see the keys and can not print them out.